# AudioRecorder not releasing

Tags: android

I can't get my head around this.

This is my code:

```
               try {
                    int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(FREQUENCY, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)*2;

                    AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord.Builder()
                            .setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION)
                            .setAudioFormat(new AudioFormat.Builder()
                                    .setEncoding(AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT)
                                    .setSampleRate(FREQUENCY)
                                    .setChannelMask(AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO)
                                    .build())
                            .setBufferSizeInBytes(bufferSize)
                            .build();

                    recorder.startRecording();


                    while (micRunning) {
                        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                        recorder.read(tempBuffer,0,bufferSize);
                        byte[] ba = new Resampler().reSample(tempBuffer, 16, 8000, 16000);
                        sendMicData(ba);
                    }
                    Log.d("Mic","Call Stop: "+recorder.getState());
                    recorder.stop();
                    Log.d("Mic","Call Release");
                    recorder.release();
                    Log.d("Mic","All done state: "+recorder.getState());
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

This works fine first time. Sometimes even 2nd and 3rd time, but then I get. Stopping and restarting the app makes it work again. I feel the release is not really releasing but I have no clue how to debug....

```
2021-08-30 18:26:12.136 23882-13893/com.example E/IAudioFlinger: createRecord returned error -1
2021-08-30 18:26:12.136 23882-13893/com.example E/AudioRecord: createRecord_l(1836047359): AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -1
2021-08-30 18:26:12.139 23882-13893/com.example E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -1.
2021-08-30 18:26:12.139 23882-13893/com.example E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2021-08-30 18:26:12.139 23882-13893/com.example W/System.err: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot create AudioRecord
2021-08-30 18:26:12.139 23882-13893/com.example W/System.err:     at android.media.AudioRecord$Builder.build(AudioRecord.java:775)
2021-08-30 18:26:12.139 23882-13893/com.example W/System.err:     at com.example.b.h.e$a.run(:90)
2021-08-30 18:26:12.139 23882-13893/com.example W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I have tried to make the `recorder` a static field, and not call the stop/release/startRecording methods, basically keeping the mic "always" listening, but it's not working reliably and it's a very very poor idea to keep the mic always on....

Any help will be appreciated...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this.
The recording was happening from a foreground service, however shortly after the screen of the phone turning off the recording was denied.

The solution was to move all the audio recording logic into a lockscreen Activity and when needed to record audio wake up the phone screen and start the Activtiy.